# jQueryUI autocomplete working with dialog just once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

After reopen Dialog autocomplete doesn't work.

```
var create_product = function () {
    isEdit = false;
    $(".dialog_create_product").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {},
        open: function (event, ui) {
    =>      $( ".getInputComponent" ).autocomplete({
                source: ['1','2','3'],
            });
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(".dialog_create_product").dialog("destroy")
        },
        beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
            closeDialog();
        }
    });
};
```

**html**

```
<div class="divInput"align="center">
    <input class = "getInputComponent" placeholder="name" type="text" maxlength="50"><button class="addComponent" >Add</button>
</div>
```

Even if autocomplete statement out of dialog function.

```
$(".dialog_create_product").on( "dialogopen", function( event, ui ) {$( ".getInputComponent" ).autocomplete({source: ['1','2','3']});} );
```

or

```
$(document).on( "dialogopen", function( event, ui ) {$( ".getInputComponent" ).autocomplete({source: ['1','2','3']});} );
```

Comment: can you explain more detail, what do you want actually?

Comment: I use dialog multiple times. Open it do some changes and save it. But when i open my dialog the second time the autocomplete form is empty. Its work normaly if  i do `.dialog("close")` but i shuld use `.dialog("destroy")` and whan i use `destroy` has a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote

```
close: function (event, ui) {
     $(".dialog_create_product").dialog("close")
},
```

Change into this

```
close: function (event, ui) {
         $(this).dialog('destroy').remove()
},
```

Comment: After closing this dialog doesn't open any more